# Using Grunt with VueJS

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been trying to setup VueJS2 with Grunt & Browserify only to keep hitting the same error of the template or render function not being defined: `[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`

Here's the code:

**Index.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import App from './components/App.vue'
import Resource from 'vue-resource'
import indexComponent from './components/index/template.vue'

Vue.use(Router)
Vue.use(Resource)

// route config
let routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: indexComponent
  },
  { path: '*', redirect: '/' }
]

// Set up a new router
let router = new Router({
  routes: routes
})

// Start up our app
new Vue({
  router: router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**gruntfile.js:**

```
 browserify: {
   js: {
     files: {
       'src/assets/js/app.js': 'src/js/index.js'
     },
     options: {
       debug: true,
       bundleDelay: 1000,
       transform: [ ["vueify"], ["babelify"] ]
     }
   }
 },
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify",
      "vueify"
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "vue": "vue/dist/vue.common.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0",
    "babelify": "^6.0.0",
    "browserify": "^14.3.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-browserify": "^5.0.0",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-sass": "^1.2.1",
    "partialify": "^3.1.5",
    "vue": "^2.3.3",
    "vue-resource": "^1.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^2.5.3",
    "vueify": "^9.4.1"
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you `import Vue from 'vue';` you'll get the runtime only build that cannot compile templates, [you need the standalone build](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only).

Comment: 'vue' is the full version though based on their documentation. Even setting an alias within the grunt browserify to 'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' still results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

this error arrives when in the system cannot find the template(HTML section of SPA) of .vue file,
in this case it may be App.vue or template.vue.

The file must be in the format of:

```
    `<template>
    </template>
    <script>
       export default{}
    </script>
    <style>
    </style>`
```